# Why does my code return 0 after entering in username and password for login

Tags: c++

So now whenever i press A or a, it shows the login function however when i type in the correct username or password it returns 0 and i am very lost as to why it happens. It works in python but in c++ i cant get it to work. This is my code... sorry if the code is very hard to understand.

// login system with login and registration and exit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char choice;
char return_page;
string username;
string password;
string confirm;
string login_username;
string login_password;
void main_page();
void registration();
void login();

void login()
{
    cout<<"Username: ";
    cin >> login_username;
    cout <<"\nPassword: ";
    cin>>login_password;
}

void registration()
{
    cout<<"Username: ";
    cin>> username;
    cout<<"\nPassword: ";
    getline(cin, password);
    cout << "\nConfirm password: ";
    cin >> confirm;
}

void main_page()
{
    cout<<"\n\t\t========Login & Registration========\n\n";
    cout<<"A.Login\n";
    cout<<"B.Registraion\n";
    cout<<"C.Exit\n";
    cout<<"Please enter which services u would prefer: ";
    cin >> choice;
}

int main()
{
    main_page();

    if(choice == 'C' || choice=='c')
    {
        return 0;    
    }

    else if(choice == 'B' || choice == 'b')
    {
        registration();
        if(password == confirm)
        {
            fstream new_file;
            new_file.open("registration.txt", ios::out);
            if(!new_file){
                cout<<"\nCannot register!";
            }
            else{
                new_file<<username;
                new_file<<password;
                new_file.close();
                cout<<"\nRegistration complete";
                main();
            }
        }
        else if(password!=confirm)
        {
            cout<<"\nThe password and confirm password is not the same, type it out again\n";
            registration();
        }
    }
    else if(choice =='A' || choice =='a')
    {
        login();
        fstream new_file;
        new_file.open("registration.txt", ios::in);
        if(!new_file){
            cout<<"\nCannot login because of some server issue";
        }
        else
        {
            string un;
            string pw;
            // reading contents of file line by line
            getline(new_file,un);
            getline(new_file, pw);
            if(un == login_username && pw == login_password)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            

            }
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hint: open `registration.txt` in your favourite text editor after your program prints `Registration complete` and check the contents of the file.

Comment: Also, you are not allowed to call `main()` manually, but this is likely not the cause of the error.

Comment: then how do i call the entire function back

Comment: You don't. There are several solutions to this problem, one would be extracting it to another funtion (which you can from itself), or simply using a loop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a newline to separate your username and password like this:

```
new_file << username << '\n';
new_file << password;
```

instead of:

```
new_file << username;  // it will concatenate username and password without
new_file << password;  // any whitespace or newline in the file
```

Also, you need to accept the Confirm password correctly, by using getline, the compiler skips it, use `std::cin` simply to get it.

After this, you'll get rid of your problem.